# In how long should I expect to be useful in a new development job?

Tags: professionalism, new-job, new-hires

I've just started a position as junior developer in web development and am anxious about how long it may take me to become actually useful to the company.

I'm doing everything I can to observe, learn and adapt, but it is already a source of stress in the position.

Obviously this will vary between companies and between roles, but roughly what timescale would one expect a junior dev to take to start really contributing? Days, weeks or even months?

Comment: There's no recommended period of time and you'd be stressing yourself unnecessarily if you're looking for a set "use-by date". It depends on the work available, the size of your company and your manager's expectations. If there's work to be done and you're capable of handling it, by all means step up to the challenge, as soon as you can. Just remember to start small

Answer (score 4):

To play a devil's advocate to the folks stating short time periods - I'm 6 months into my current position and it's still not expected for me to be fully up and running(though I am 'useful').

Why do the numbers vary so much? Because every project is different. A simple project(creating static webpages for a client) is going to have a much shorter runup period than a complex project(A custom framework on top of 10 different APIs). Simple systems should take less time, so a few weeks for a Jr Developer, to be up and running. Complex systems could take up to and/or over a year.

The other thing you should consider is: "What does 'useful' mean?" Even if you don't know the ins and outs of a project you can be 'useful' by providing code reviews, making minor bug fixes, testing, etc. A lot of times the stuff you're feeling right now, though, isn't really about usefulness and is more about being much less experienced in a project than those around you. Most people want to feel confident and able to answer general questions about a system *now*. Never mind that it took your peers months or years to get to where they are and that some of them have reaped the benefit of learning the system as it was built around them; no we humans want to be owners/masters/controllers **now**.

Having to ask for help, having to check with someone else(especially, perhaps, in a poorly documented environment) can make us feel useless. It can make us feel as though we aren't doing anything helpful because, after all, we couldn't do it on our own. In some way this isn't a bad feeling - having this push to be the guru means you're going to be driven to learn and attain knowledge much faster than someone who doesn't have this drive.

Ultimately there's no 'expected' timeline for major contributions. Arguably the point of Jr Devs is that they aren't making 'major contributions', they are learning by making minor contributions and supporting the devs and Sr. devs in the major ones. It may be, and I would say it's pretty likely, that you are contributing just fine for your level and timeline, you just feel like you should be doing more. Use that feeling, that drive, to really push yourself but take it a little easier on yourself as well. If you are working hard, doing what is asked of you and working to get better every day then you are contributing.

Comment: 6 months to fully contributing isn't unreasable, and on the other end, after 5 years in the same position, you have been there too long and are likely not contributing fully anymore (by same position, I mean exact same role, if you change roles or teams, the clock resets)

Comment: @BillLeeper: I think that depends on the job. In some jobs that could be the case. In jobs that are cutting edge in some way it's possible for it not to be the case. It can also depend on the position. A dev1 in a web app developing shop? Yeah if you don't move up then you should move one. A Sr Tech lead in an R&D shop? 5 years is just scratching the surface.

Comment: To add to Nahkki's comment, It heavily depends on the problem and business domains. There are some domains that take 6 to 12 months just to begin becoming competent at grasping the fundamentals. If the job was purely programming/technical then absolutely someone should be productive within a month or two at the most. However, with regards to junior developers it tends to be very company specific. Process oriented companies want to take the time to ensure junior's learn the "company" way of doing things and are willing to give up the short-term productivity for long-term gains.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're asking the wrong people. :) You should be asking your manager/boss, and you should communicate that you're unsure of how you are currently doing and how quickly you should get up to speed.

I started a new job 2 months ago. I felt very much the same way as you. I do everything I can to observer and learn, but there is still a great deal I don't know. I was very very worried I wasn't working fast enough and I went to my manager and told him just that, and I was told I was doing fine and I was right on track for where they expected me to be.

Every job is different. The learning curve of the framework and code base can vary. The expectations of a new hire vary between position and experience level. Asking us on the internet how long it should take you to get up to speed I feel will only make you more stressed.

Schedule a short review meeting with your manager/boss/whoever you report to, and find out directly from them. If they feel you're on track, keep doing what you're doing. If they feel you're lagging a bit, DON'T PANIC! Ask what you can do to get back on track, come up with a plan with them and schedule a follow up meeting a few weeks to see if you're on the right path.

Answer (score 2):

I personally would expect someone to be contributing by the second week at the very latest (and experienced person I would expect to be contributing by day 2. But I also would make sure that person has the tools he needs to do something by then and that he was assigned something relatively easy. I would probably also pair him with someone, but he should be actively contributing to the pair by the second week.

Some managers don't make sure new employees are given what they need to get rolling quickly. Some don't give assignments immediately. If you aren't getting management support, you need to actively ask for something to do to start with. You will learn more from doing an actual task than from observing. If you wait for things to be given to you, then you may be looked at as passive and uninterested and those are bad qualities for your manager to think you have. So get out there and ask for tasks if you haven't been given them. If you have been given tasks, why are you still observing? You need to be more active.

If you spend too long waiting for work and passively observing (and too long is subjective and based on the company, the situation and the manager -- in the days of formal training programs, it might be several weeks of training first, but those days are long gone), it is easy to get rid of someone who doesn't appear to be stepping up to contribute.

Comment: Very important point made "But I also would make sure that person has the tools he needs to do something by then and that he was assigned something relatively easy."

Comment: There is a difference between doing useful work and doing high level work. And it does depend on theworkplace because there has to be some useful work a junior can do that is assigned. (Of course if don't have any of that why are you hiring junior level people to begin with?) But I expect everyone to be doing something useful and contributing to actual projects fairly quickly. That does not mean fully trained.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what type of work you are doing. I would expect you to be able to contribute in small ways after a few weeks, but I would expect you to be very productive after a year (and start transitioning from junior to mid-level).

At first some things are easier than others and will help you get familiar with the code. I would ask the senior devs to start giving you easy bugs to fix that will help you get familiar with the code. Is there a dropdown not showing a correct value on a web page? Duplicate the error in the dev environment, then find out where the dropdown values come from in the database. Show your solution to the senior dev. Is a page not displaying correctly in IE but works fine in Firefox and Chrome? Go investigate that. You have to find out how to set up the project, where the code is, etc.

You can also help test some changes the senior devs made, at least at the beginning. Is there something in particular you are worried about? Would it be possible for you to give an example of a situation where you felt you could not contribute?